# i need help on "this" keyword and inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, this, abstract-class, virtual-functions

```
abstract class BaseClass
{
    public virtual void Accept(IVisitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.Visit(this);
    }
}

class DerivedClass: BaseClass
{
}

interface IVisitor
{
    void Visit(BaseClass baseEntity);
    void Visit(DerivedClass derivedEntity);
}

class Visitor : IVisitor
{
    public void Visit(DerivedClass derivedEntity)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Derived Entity visited");
    }

    public void Visit(BaseClass baseEntity)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Base Entity visited");
    }
}
```

After above declerations

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DerivedClass derived = new DerivedClass();
        Visitor visitor = new Visitor();
        derived.Accept(visitor);
    }
}
```

produces

```
"Base Entity visited"
```

however i expect it to produce

```
"Derived Entity visited"
```

- Can anyone explain why?
- What should i do to produce "Derived Entity visited"? I don't want to override "Accept" function.

Comment: I think you are trying to conflate polymorphism and method overloads in a way that is unlikely to give you the results you want... ever. Probably should just stick to polymorphism.

Comment: i am trying to understand visitor design pattern by implementing a simple sample. what you suggest is overriding the function, right?

Comment: Its been a while since I implemented Visitor, but I don't remember it every having method overloading involved; so yeah.

Comment: Discussion section at https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor

Comment: Reading that document, its more the polymorphic example I expected, while each class has overloads for the visitor objects (which still seems to violate OCP to me), derived classes override them.

Comment: you are correct but i did not like the idea of copying and pasting the same code to every derived class. Especially when i read that this pattern tries not to change already existing classes.. however i see there is an overhead.. it was a nice discussion. thank you.

Comment: That's what I mean, by doing the overloads for every one of the other derived classes you violate Open-Closed. I'm sure there is a way to do visitor that doesn't require them, I just don't remember it off the top of my head :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are facing here is with multiple dispatching. Compiler selects the base class because you are calling it from the base class. One quick solution you can add is to use `dynamic`:

```
public virtual void Accept(IVisitor visitor)
{
    visitor.Visit(this as dynamic);
}
```

You trick the compiler to not know the actual type of the object - and call the correct Visit overload.

And here is some extra reading from [MSND](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnhar/2011/04/05/visitor-and-multiple-dispatch-via-c-dynamic/)

Comment: I have no idea if this will work, but I'm pretty sure that you don't want to be doing this as a matter of practice

Comment: @MustafaDüman `dynamic` in general causes extra runtime overhead and effectively inserts duck typing into a very statically typed language. I'm not going to say you should *never* use it, but it shouldn't just be thrown around.

Comment: i see your point. thanks. In this sample, if i use "dynamic" my code looks cleaner.. If i don't use it i should copy and paste the same function in to every derived class (although just one derived class is present in this sample).

Comment: @MustafaDüman See my other comment, I think the reason you need this hack is because you are implementing the pattern incorrectly.

Comment: You *may* also have to cast the visitor object to a dynamic, I've found in practice.

Answer (score 3):

Overloads are resolved at compile time, so the when compiling your `BaseClass`, the compiler is going to pick the `Visitor.Visit` overload that matches its compile time type (`BaseClass`).

When using the Visitor pattern, you typically will want to override the `Accept` method in derived classes.

While you can avoid this using `dynamic`, you will lose the advantage of static type checking if you do so.

[This article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/588882/TheplusVisitorplusPatternplusExplained) shows an example of the visitor pattern in C# where the `Accept` method is overridden in derived classes.

Comment: ergwun i marked JleruOHeP's answer as correct answer since it gives me what i want.. but @BradleyDotNet's and your comments are also enlightening about using dynamic. thank you..